# How to access Dynamic Zones and Components as JSON in Strapi backend

Tags: json, strapi

I am trying to search for certain data inside a Collection Type or Single Type through localhost://1337.
Strapi allows you to search the json data of a basic structure such as: localhost:1337/articles/ OR even localhost:1337/articles/1.

But I wish to go deeper and access the json of a dynamic zone or a component inside of a single type or a collection type.
In the settings of Strapi under Permissions/Content-Manager you have options for finding collection types and anything inside of that specific collection type.
For example `/content-manager/collection-types/:model`
[image]

In the above image you will see a dynamic zone with a Component called Data which has another component called Technology inside it.
I wish to somehow access the `Technology` component directly as a json in localhost://1337.
An example of me trying to access technology component:
http://localhost:1337/navigation/solutions/Data/technology

I would like to know how to access technology.
Strapi explains that you must go through this specific manner but it doesn't seem to work for me:

```
/content-manager/collection-types/:model
```

Comment: similar problem, only basic fields are visible via API, dynamic zones invisible

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this?